# Will resizing the VM memory or disk size cause loss of installed application in the VM?

Tags: azure, resize, virtual-machine

Will resizing the VM size in terms of memory or disk size cause loss of installed application in the VM ?

What is the possibility of this happening ?

I have a VM deployed in azure.

Answer (score 1):

Azure VMs can be resized and involves short downtime depending on the scenario. But it will not impact your installed application. Your VHD file will be stored there at blog storage. For more information, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/110922/existing-data-will-be-lost-if-i-resizeincrese-ubun.html).

From https://petri.com/resize-azure-virtual-machine

> By deallocating the virtual machine (Azure shutdown, not a guest OS
> shutdown), all of the possible options in the region are made
> available, and the resize process will migrate the virtual machine to
> a new compute cluster.

also, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/resize-vm

> Deallocating the VM releases any dynamic IP addresses assigned to the
> VM. The OS and data disks are not affected.